# logic behind vanity numbers

Tags: vb6, logic

i started learning to program a few months ago. Totally love the idea and the concept of it. Im currently learning to program in vb6 as ive heard it is easy to learn.

Id like to make a basic program where the inputed phone number gives out vanity numbers for it. This sounded very easy to me until  i started gathering ideas and the logic behind the program.

I cant seem to figure out the logic behind it to save my life. I have googled and have done some research but wasnt able to find anything on the topic

If someone could explain to me how i can approach this idea, id very much appreciate that

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a vanity number or we cannot answer. For discussion I'm assuming the last 4 digits to be two pairs.

This is VBScript. Vbscript is legal VB6. However you'll have to set a reference to *Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5*.

```
xmlstring = "2756-1122"
Set regEx = New RegExp
regEx.Pattern = "\d\d\d\d-(\d)\1(\d)\2"
regEx.IgnoreCase = True
regEx.Global = True
Msgbox regEx.Test(xmlstring)
```

Test that the number is 4 digits, a dash, then two pairs of numbers.

**\d** Matches a digit character. Equivalent to [0-9].

**\num** Matches num, where num is a positive integer. A reference back to remembered matches. For example, "`(.)\1`" matches two consecutive identical characters.

Comment: Also VB6 has the `Like` operator (not a function), a semi regular expresion tester only. It's very limited.You could also generate last two numbers being a pair `TelNum = 24347600:For x = 1 to 9: TelNum = TelNum + 11:TelNumStr = TelNumStr & TelNum & vbcrlf:Next:msgbox TelNumStr`